# Difference in cypher peformance depending on phrasing?

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have a created a test dataset resembling some client data with the following structure:

```
   *1                100k              *3..30
[:author]-------->  person  <---------[:member]
    |                 |                  |
    |               *2..8                |
    |              [:topic]              |
    |                 |                  |
    |    *3..8        V        *3..8     |
article-[:topic]->  topic  <-[:topic]- project
    1m                1k                 20k
```

The numbers mean e.g. I have 1 million articles, each with one author, and each article has between 3 and 8 rels to one of 1000 topics.

Now I have two questions:

**First: does this layout make sense**? Topics become supernodes - would it be better to have them as attributes on the nodes?

Second, I see huge performance differences for a query, depending on how I express it. The idea is to find people who have worked ona project together, and also share a personal interest in a topic:

*query1*

```
match 
    n:person<-[:member]-p:project-[:member]->m, 
    n-[:topic]->t,
    m-[:topic]->t 
where 
    n.name='person1215' and 
    n<>m 
return 
    m,t;
```

This returns in `1500ms-9000ms` range.

*query2* is much faster:

```
match 
    n:person<-[:member]-p:project-[:member]->m, 
    n-[:topic]->t1, 
    m-[:topic]->t2  
where 
    n.name='person1250' and 
    n<>m and 
    t1=t2 
return 
    t1,m;
```

returns in `200ms-400ms`.

**Second: why is query2 so much faster?** 
How would one see that from just looking at that query?

Profiler output for *query1*:

```
ColumnFilter(symKeys=["n", "t", "m", "  UNNAMED14", "p", "  UNNAMED51", "  UNNAMED35", "  UNNAMED66"], returnItemNames=["m", "t"], _rows=3, _db_hits=0)
Filter(pred="((NOT(n == m) AND hasLabel(p: project)) AND hasLabel(p: project))", _rows=3, _db_hits=0)
  PatternMatch(g="(p)-['  UNNAMED35']-(m),(p)-['  UNNAMED14']-(n),(m)-['  UNNAMED66']-(t),(n)-['  UNNAMED51']-(t)", _rows=3, _db_hits=0)
    SchemaIndex(identifier="n", _db_hits=0, _rows=1, label="person", query="Literal(person1215)", property="name")
```

and for *query2*:

```
ColumnFilter(symKeys=["n", "  UNNAMED67", "m", "  UNNAMED14", "t2", "p", "  UNNAMED51", "t1", "  UNNAMED35"], returnItemNames=["t1", "m"], _rows=2, _db_hits=0)
Filter(pred="(((NOT(n == m) AND t1 == t2) AND hasLabel(p: project)) AND hasLabel(p: project))", _rows=2, _db_hits=0)
  PatternMatch(g="(p)-['  UNNAMED35']-(m),(p)-['  UNNAMED14']-(n),(m)-['  UNNAMED67']-(t2),(n)-['  UNNAMED51']-(t1)", _rows=2, _db_hits=0)
    SchemaIndex(identifier="n", _db_hits=0, _rows=1, label="person", query="Literal(person1250)", property="name")
```

Thanks a lot,

Joerg

Comment: Your query1 and query2 are using different users (1215 and 1250). If one has written more articles than the other, that could account for the difference since execution time scales with the number of relationships you need to traverse.

Comment: Good thought, but thats not the reason. Even for the same users the result is as described. I have different numbers in the question because I was doing multiple runs for each query to get the time ranges, but also to avoid using query caches.

Answer (score 1):

Joerg, it might be that you found a bug in the pattern matcher selection, those queries should actually use the traversal matcher.

We'll follow up with that one if you raise a GitHub issue. Thanks a lot!!

For the "supernodes"-topics it might make sense to use less generic relationship-types which allow a sub-organization (in memory) of the relationships of the nodes. E.g. `:project_topic`, `article_topic`, `:interest_topic`. Could you try this out?

Then your query would be:

```
match 
    n:person<-[:member]-p:project-[:member]->m, 
    n-[:interest_topic]->t,
    m-[:interest_topic]->t 
where 
    n.name='person1215' and 
    n<>m 
return 
    m,t;
```

Btw. due to the node-uniqueness constraints `m` should actually not be the same as n, did you see that in your query?

It would be also interesting what happens if you leave of the second label check (for `:project`, just curious).

Also, please note that 2.0 is not performance optimized yet. For a dedicated person lookup it will be much faster closer to GA.